# How to start subscription after another subscription ends

Tags: angular, rxjs

How to start a subscription after another subscription ends with rxjs operators in angular with 2 selects.

```js
this.store.pipe(
      takeUntil(this.onDestroy$),
      select(getDatasetIsCreation),
      filter((datasetCreation) => datasetCreation))
      .subscribe((isCreated) => {
        this.isCustomScriptDatasetCreated = isCreated;
        this.updateDatasets();
      });

    this.store.pipe(select(state => state.plutoQueue.newDatasetId)).subscribe((datasetId) => {
      const newDataset = Number(datasetId);
      const datasets = this.datasets.map((item) => item.datasetId);
      const datasetExist = datasets.includes(newDataset);
      if (!datasetExist && this.isCustomScriptDatasetCreated) {
        this.store.dispatch(loadSelectedDatasets({ payload: [newDataset] }));
        this.store.dispatch(changeIsDatasetCreation({payload: false}));
      }
    });
```

Comment: have you tried the [concat](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/concat) operator?

Comment: @Edward if possible maybe u can show, structure how to do this concat with 2 selects please?

Comment: why not use the second inside the first subscription's result handling?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need start

```
this.store.pipe(select(state => state.plutoQueue.newDatasetId)).subscribe((datasetId) => {
      const newDataset = Number(datasetId);
      const datasets = this.datasets.map((item) => item.datasetId);
      const datasetExist = datasets.includes(newDataset);
      if (!datasetExist && this.isCustomScriptDatasetCreated) {
        this.store.dispatch(loadSelectedDatasets({ payload: [newDataset] }));
        this.store.dispatch(changeIsDatasetCreation({payload: false}));
      }
    });
```

when first subscription i.e.

```
this.store.pipe(
      takeUntil(this.onDestroy$),
      select(getDatasetIsCreation),
      filter((datasetCreation) => datasetCreation))
      .subscribe((isCreated) => {
        this.isCustomScriptDatasetCreated = isCreated;
        this.updateDatasets();
      });
```

ends, if yes, I would suggest you 2 points,

1. Do go through decision tree from rxjs and put your conditions there and in future also you will be able to take better decisions based on it,

[Rxjs Decision tree](https://rxjs.dev/operator-decision-tree)

2. You need contact for your problem so you can try something like below,

   ```
    import { concat } from 'rxjs';

    const one = this.store.pipe(
          takeUntil(this.onDestroy$),
          select(getDatasetIsCreation),
          filter((datasetCreation) => datasetCreation))
          .subscribe((isCreated) => {
            this.isCustomScriptDatasetCreated = isCreated;
            this.updateDatasets();
          });

    const two = this.store.pipe(select(state => state.plutoQueue.newDatasetId)).subscribe((datasetId) => {
          const newDataset = Number(datasetId);
          const datasets = this.datasets.map((item) => item.datasetId);
          const datasetExist = datasets.includes(newDataset);
          if (!datasetExist && this.isCustomScriptDatasetCreated) {
            this.store.dispatch(loadSelectedDatasets({ payload: [newDataset] }));
            this.store.dispatch(changeIsDatasetCreation({payload: false}));
          }
        });

    const three = concat(one, two);

    three.subscribe(result => {// do your action here})
   ```